# Azure Stack marketplace offering

Tags: azure-stack

I am trying to publish my offering in Azure stack using doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-create-and-publish-marketplace-item?view=azs-2002. 
But I have linked templates and in manifest file I have provided the paths of artifacts. But I am not clear of what does "isDefault" means ?
is there any in detail guide regarding creation and publishing an offer on Azure stack?

Answer (score 1):

"isDefault" is used to denote the main template of your marketplace item. You can indeed have linked templates in the main template, but ensure you only have one entry in the manifest.json file.

Here are some detailed blog posts that walk one through the process of creating and publishing a custom Azure Stack Hub Marketplace item:

- [Adding a Marketplace Item to Azure Stack](https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimitedMRP/azurestack/azurestack-34-marketplace.html)
- [Adding and Using OS Gallery Items to Azure Stack TP2](https://azurestack.blog/2016/10/adding-and-using-os-gallery-items-to-azure-stack-tp2/)
- [Adding and Using DSC for Linux Gallery Item to Azure Stack TP2](https://azurestack.blog/2016/10/adding-and-using-dsc-for-linux-gallery-item-to-azure-stack-tp2/)